# Sql query to find total percentage

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT tblItems.ItemType, Count(tblItems.ItemType) AS total
FROM tblItems
WHERE (((tblItems.Pool) BETWEEN 188 AND 218))
GROUP BY tblItems.ItemType;
```

This is my current query and it prints out the items in one row and the total times they appeared in another row named total. I would like to be able to make another row with the percentage this is of the total items. I tried adding after the count `(total/SUM(total)) AS pct_total` but this does not work. The error I get is  "subqueries cannot be used in the expression (Sum(total))"

Comment: Define "doesn't work". If you mean you get an error, that is probably because you forgot the closing parentheses after `Count(tblItems.ItemType`.

Comment: I forgot to write that in when writing this, the error I'm getting is

Comment: Okay, but please, if you get that error in another query, then please post that other query (too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
SELECT i.ItemType, Count(i.ItemType) AS total,
       Count(*) * 1.0 / (select count(*) from tblItems WHERE Pool between 188 and 218) as ratio
FROM tblItems as i
WHERE i.Pool BETWEEN 188 AND 218
GROUP BY i.ItemType;
```

Comment: This seems to be on the right track, let me play with this and see what I get

Answer (score 1):

you may need to use sub query.. try like this:

```
select Itemtype,(total/SUM(total)) AS pct_total from
(SELECT tblItems.ItemType as Itemtype, Count(tblItems.ItemType) AS total
FROM tblItems
WHERE (((tblItems.Pool) BETWEEN 188 AND 218))
GROUP BY tblItems.ItemType) as A
Group By A.Itemtype;
```

Comment: I'm getting a "syntax error in FROM clause using this

Comment: Ah it didn't like where the semicolon was but now it's "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Itemtype' as part of an aggregate function.

Comment: Ahhh... sorry.. busy in someother work.. will edit to make it correct..Actually we need to group by Item type since we are taking it in Where clause